# Play Framework (Scala) Template

Tags: scala, playframework

Can someone explain to me what the Template function does in the following code:

```
object Users extends Controller {   
    def show(id:Long) = Template("user" -> User.findById(id))
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Could you maybe give more context, or point to a source somewhere?

Comment: It's here http://scala.playframework.org/documentation/scala-0.9.1/controllers#ScalacontrollersareObjects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's syntactic sugar to create a template. In this example, it is a call to the function:

```
def Template(args: (Symbol, Any)*)
```

(defined [here](https://github.com/playframework/play-scala/blob/master/src/play/mvc/ScalaController.scala#L81)). Itself just forwards the arguments to the `ScalaControllerCompatibility` object (same file), that rewrites them so that the method, finally, creates a [`Template`](https://github.com/playframework/play-scala/blob/master/src/play/mvc/results/Template.scala) instance.